# Kerberos: How to change the password after "password has expired exception" in Java

Tags: java, kerberos

I am using the Krb5LoginModule (com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule)
for Kerberos authentication. 
This works fine for all AD-Accounts until their password expires. 
Then I get following exception: 
KrbException: Password has expired - change password to reset (23)

How can I do this with java 8?

Comment: Sounds like you should ask the AD:s to change their passwords before they expire. This is a sysadmin issue, not a programming issue.

Comment: This has to be possible with java. Saw an implementation in Java 6 but Oracle changed a lot. I tried to rebuild it, but I failed. So I cannot be the only one who need´s this.

Comment: How can you do *what* with Java 8?

Comment: I want to change an ad-user-account password via java. If I get the exception: "Password has expired - change password to reset (23)" it must be possible to change this password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error I got was a kerberos error. I builded my own kadmin/changepw@domain message and after sending it to the server i got something like "invalid message". But for all who have the same problem: ApacheDS was the solution. They have a kerberos client which was very helpful.

Comment: Hi Mex, 

Are you able to work with Apache DS? IF yes, can you please share me the procedure to generate tickets and do some basic authentication?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily find bunch of examples on how to change user's password in AD from Java program. But you're saying you even have the code. What exactly failed? Have you tried to research the compiler error message you're getting?
Also, where this "Password has expired exception" is coming from? Security provider?